# What should be the strategy for Unit testing a method calling other methods in the same class?

Tags: unit-testing, testng, mockito, spock, powermockito

I am writing unit tests for a class that has a method that calls other methods of the same class. This is leading to a lot of scenarios to be tested.

I am of the opinion that I can spy() the behaviour of the method calls so that I am testing only the method under test and not bothered about other methods behaviour. I will cover them through a separate test for each of those methods.

```
class MyClass{

  public void myMethodToBeTested(){
     aPrivateMethod();
     aPublicMethod();
  }

  private void aPrivateMethod(){
   // doing something
   // Has some if else scenarios
  }

  public void aPublicMethod(){
   // doing something
   // Has some if else scenarios
  }
}
```

What would be best way to unit test this class?

Answer (score 3):

You should test by calling the external interface of the class i.e. the public methods.

If those methods call private methods in the same class, then those private methods need to be fully covered too - otherwise how would they be tested?

Stubbing or spying only makes sense for calls to resources or classes outside the class under test.

You're trying to test the entire class, not just individual methods.

Comment: Spock's "where" block really helps to vary the public method parameters to cover all lines within the private methods

Answer (score 0):

In my view the aPrivateMethod could go to a separate class as public and also the body of the aPublicMethod could be a different method in that class.

After this refactoring you can inject the new class and call those methods in the corresponding places.

When it comes to testing, you could mock/stub those methods and test the myMethodToBeTested().

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd change the private method to default / package-level.  That way, a unit test occupying the same package can access it but other methods, outside of that package, can't touch it.  Not quite the same thing as private scope, but close enough most of the time.

Then, setup a Spy() on MyClass.

In case you're not clear on that term:

- A Mock() on a class will always return null or 0 to any method call
- A Stub() on a class lets you define what certain methods in that class should do, but anything you DON'T explicitly specify always returns a null or 0
- A Spy() lets you create an object of a class, with all methods in place EXCEPT you can override some of those methods

So create a Spy(MyClass), specify what aPrivateMethod() and aPublicMethod() should return for testing purposes then call myMethodToBeTested() and see what is returned.  In your example, that method is void, so it doesn't return anything.  But you can always:

1. define a variable outside of the Spy()
2. have aPublicMethod() set / modify the variable based on inputs or internal state (your overriding methods in your Spy() can take parameters)
3. call myMethodToBeTested()
4. check the contents of that variable